# Structural idea for CNN with MNIST dataset

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to create a convolutional neural network to recognize handwritten digit (from MNIST dataset), and I wonder what would be a good structure for rotated digits, right now I can only think of going deeper, adding more layers. Any ideas on how to build such a CNN for recognizing rotated MNIST digits? I'm working with tensorflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any standard architecture, see [keras/mnist_cnn.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) for example, and train it on rotated data.

In the keras example, for the channels last format, you could do:

```
x_train = np.rot90(x_train, k=1, axes=(1,2))
```

to rotate your input 90 degress, for example.